# SOAP deserialization: null fields of base class

Tags: c#, soap

I have some classes generated from WSDL (by VS add service reference):

**getClientDataResponseType:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates")]
public partial class getClientDataResponseType : baseResponse {

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("clientData", typeof(clientDataWithId), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("clientNotFoundExceptionResponse", typeof(clientNotFoundExceptionResponseType), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("genericExceptionResponse", typeof(genericExceptionResponseType), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("templateList", typeof(templateList), Order=0)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
}
```

**templateList:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates")]
public partial class templateList : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private templateListElement[] templateField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("template", Order=0)]
    public templateListElement[] template {
        get {
            return this.templateField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("template");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**templateListElement:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates")]
public partial class templateListElement : templateType {

    private string templateIdField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string templateId {
        get {
            return this.templateIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.templateIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("templateId");
        }
    }
}
```

and finally **templateType:**

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(templateListElement))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2558.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates")]
public partial class templateType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string descriptionField;

    private string accountIdField;

    private string processingSystemField;

    private string templateType1Field;

    private templateAttributeList attributesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string description {
        get {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descriptionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("description");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public string accountId {
        get {
            return this.accountIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.accountIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("accountId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
    public string processingSystem {
        get {
            return this.processingSystemField;
        }
        set {
            this.processingSystemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("processingSystem");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("templateType", Order=3)]
    public string templateType1 {
        get {
            return this.templateType1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.templateType1Field = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("templateType1");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
    public templateAttributeList attributes {
        get {
            return this.attributesField;
        }
        set {
            this.attributesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("attributes");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and when i got responce from web service, props defined in base *templateType* class was filling nulls values, and only *templateIdField* defined in derived *templateListElement* class was parsed correct

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pa="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header />
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <pa:getClientDataResponse>
      <pa:return>1</pa:return>
      <pa:returnCode>0</pa:returnCode>
      <pa:clientData>
        <pa:surname>Abernathy</pa:surname>
        <pa:name>Dolores</pa:name>
        <pa:patronymic>not_present</pa:patronymic>
        <pa:birthDate>1979-07-05</pa:birthDate>
        <pa:document>
          <pa:docType>21</pa:docType>
          <pa:docNumber>577507</pa:docNumber>
          <pa:docDate>2002-11-12</pa:docDate>
        </pa:document>
        <pa:clientId>6ef27ac9-1a42-430e-bd2f-9cfb8a824b7e</pa:clientId>
      </pa:clientData>
      <pa:templateList>
        <template xmlns="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates">
          <templateId>26236b96-69ed-49be-9be7-74e0342e50bf</templateId>
          <templateType>HashPAN</templateType>
          <description>some_description</description>
          <accountId>234234234</accountId>
          <processingSystem>TCS</processingSystem>
          <attributes>
          </attributes>
        </template>
        <template xmlns="http://api.company.ru/sid/paymenttemplates">
          <templateId>fc124296-4ff4-4842-a78c-2ff92b100c88</templateId>
          <templateType>Other</templateType>
          <description>some_description</description>
          <accountId>79048931512</accountId>
          <processingSystem>TCH</processingSystem>
          <attributes>
            <attribute>
              <name>owner_family</name>
              <value>Dolores</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>owner_name</name>
              <value>Abernathy</value>
            </attribute>
            <attribute>
              <name>owner_patronymic</name>
              <value>not_present</value>
            </attribute>
          </attributes>
        </template>
      </pa:templateList>
    </pa:getClientDataResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

test code

```
var result2 = client.getClientData(new getClientDataRequestType {token = tok, codeDoc = controlNumber});

templateListElement template = null;
clientDataWithId data = null;
foreach (var item in result2.Items)
    if (item is templateList)
    {
        var list = (templateList) item;
        foreach (var t in list.template)
            Helper.Log(t.ObjToString());
    }
    else if (item is clientDataWithId)
    {
        data = (clientDataWithId) item;
        Helper.Log(data.ObjToString());
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown item type!");
    }
```

as you can see null values was logged here for all props defined in base class (description, accountId, processingSystem etc..)

```
[2018.07.10 12.37.20] TemplateServiceReference.templateListElement
templateId: 26236b96-69ed-49be-9be7-74e0342e50bf
description: (null)
accountId: (null)
processingSystem: (null)
templateType1: (null)
attributes: (null)

[2018.07.10 12.37.20] TemplateServiceReference.templateListElement
templateId: fc124296-4ff4-4842-a78c-2ff92b100c88
description: (null)
accountId: (null)
processingSystem: (null)
templateType1: (null)
attributes: (null)
```

Can anybody help me solve this trouble?

Comment: When using derived classes a type must be added to the xml for the code to deserialize properly.  You can put test data into your classes and then serialize the test data and you will see the xml contain extra attributes that are missing from you xml input.

Comment: Member order in responce are important in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in elements ORDER in responce. It dosnt match the WSDL schema. I just delete order=0,1,2 etc.. from attrs props and deserialization now work correct!